# group by WEEK() malfunction for 2013

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure what has happened exactly.

I have a query which gets all sales made in a week that has slightly malfunctioned breaking up a week in to 2, here is the query...

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(SUM(sell_price), 2) AS sell_price, 
    ROUND(SUM(buy_price/100*20), 2) AS fees, 
    ROUND(SUM(buy_price), 2) AS buy_price, 
    ROUND(SUM(sell_price/100*80 - buy_price), 2) AS margin, 
    time 
    FROM order_items 
    GROUP BY WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(time), 1) 
    ORDER BY WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(time), 1) DESC
```

This outputs the following

```
Sell Price      Fees    Buy Price   Margin  Date
44.01           4.46    22.30       12.91   31-12-2012
464.00          46.58   232.90      138.36  27-12-2012
313.82          31.80   159.01      92.06   10-12-2012
669.91          62.13   310.67      225.26  03-12-2012
265.88          25.57   127.84      84.87   02-12-2012
208.58          15.78   78.88       87.98   24-11-2012
176.90          16.32   81.59       59.93   01-01-2013
```

As you can see from the table you have the week beginning from the 31/12/12 being cut off from sales made in 2013, the sales are also not being returned in descending order as sales from 2013 should be displayed at the top of the table.

The table returned should look something like...

```
Sell Price      Fees    Buy Price   Margin  Date
220.2           20.78   103.90      72.84   31-12-2012
464.00          46.58   232.90      138.36  27-12-2012
313.82          31.80   159.01      92.06   10-12-2012
669.91          62.13   310.67      225.26  03-12-2012
265.88          25.57   127.84      84.87   02-12-2012
208.58          15.78   78.88       87.98   24-11-2012
```

Comment: @bluefeet I must misunderstand how the function works because im assuming a week is from monday-sunday

Comment: `Week` is week number not monday-sunday

Comment: not sure what the answer is for you, but maybe http://sqlfiddle.com will be your friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(SUM(sell_price), 2) AS sell_price, 
    ROUND(SUM(buy_price/100*20), 2) AS fees, 
    ROUND(SUM(buy_price), 2) AS buy_price, 
    ROUND(SUM(sell_price/100*80 - buy_price), 2) AS margin, 
    DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(time), INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) - 1) DAY) AS fdow 
    FROM order_items 
    GROUP BY fdow
    ORDER BY fdow DESC
```

Comment: I've tried another approach but your expected results doesn't show a row for 2013

Comment: I was contemplating an answer along the lines of yours. Indeed, your DATE_SUB() expression gives you both a grouping criterion and a value to display in the output (the week's starting date). But you should probably get rid of `time` in the SELECT clause, it just doesn't make any sense in this context.

Comment: @AndriyM - true about the time column... removed.

Answer (score 1):

The splitting of the values is correct. The [`Week()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function returns week number not Monday-Sunday values.

So `12/31/2012` is in the final week of 2012 and `1/1/2013` is in Week 1 of 2013.

See [SQL Fiddle with a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcaf7/1) of `Week()` function.

You might want to look at the [`WeekOfYear()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) function to see if that would work for you ([See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcaf7/4)):

```
select weekofyear(yourcol)
from yourtable
```

Comment: Yeah, you're essentially getting `DESC` of the values `52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 1`

Comment: I can see what the problem is now.

Comment: @mk_89 you can try `weekofyear()` instead of `week()` it does not appear to split the week in the same way -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dd75/1

Comment: @bluefeet ok I will look into it